# CheckedListbox doesn't show the text

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I try to implement CheckedListbox in my wpf. I want to fill it from a List, then select Items of a List with the checkbox

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding selectedList}" >
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding CheckedList.SetText}" IsChecked="{Binding CheckedList.Checked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
```

and this is my VM Class

```
    public class CheckedList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {private string _text;
        public string SetText
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SetText");
            }
        }

        private bool _checked;
        public bool Checked
        {
            get { return _checked; }
            set
            {
                _checked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
            }
        }
        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }
    }


    class MigratorAdvancedMigrationOptionsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Migrator _Migrator { get; set; }
        CloseClass _Close { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand<IClosable> CloseWindowCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand<IShowable> ShowWindowCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand<IShowable> BackWindowCommand { get; private set; }
        public string WindowTitle { get; private set; }
        Window _window;
        private RelayCommand<object> _setRequirements;
        public ObservableCollection<string> List { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<CheckedList> selectedList { get; set; }


        public MigratorAdvancedMigrationOptionsViewModel(Migrator _migrator, CloseClass _Close)
        {
            this.ShowWindowCommand = new RelayCommand<IShowable>(this.ShowWindow);
            this.BackWindowCommand = new RelayCommand<IShowable>(this.Back);
            this._setRequirements = new RelayCommand<object>(Set_Requirements);
            _onClosingCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(OnClosing_Command);
            _Migrator = _migrator;
            this._Close = _Close;

            List = (ObservableCollection<string>)_migrator.GetTables();
            selectedList = new ObservableCollection<CheckedList>();
            CheckedList checkedList= new CheckedList();
            foreach (string item in List)
            {

                checkedList.SetText = item;
                checkedList.Checked = false;
                selectedList.Add(checkedList);
            }

        }



        private RelayCommand<object> _onClosingCommand;
        public ICommand OnClosingCommand
        {
            get { return _onClosingCommand; }
        }

        private void OnClosing_Command(object obj)
        {
            _Close.IsClosedFromButton = true;
            _Close.CancelConfirmation(obj);
        }


        public ICommand SetRequirements
        {
            get { return _setRequirements; }
        }


        private void Set_Requirements(object obj)
        {

            _window = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows[4];
            _Close.Set_Requirements(_window);
        }


        private void ShowWindow(IShowable window)
        {

        }


        private void Back(object obj)
        {
            _Close.Back(3, 4);
            _Migrator._windowState = SpaixDM.NetDesktop.Models.WindowState.options;
        }





        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }
    }
```

By debugging i see only a Textbox with 5 checkbox (5 Items in the selectedList) and nothing more.
I tried also this variation

```
    public class CheckedList 
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool Value { get; set; }
    }


    class MigratorAdvancedMigrationOptionsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Migrator _Migrator { get; set; }
        CloseClass _Close { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand<IClosable> CloseWindowCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand<IShowable> ShowWindowCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand<IShowable> BackWindowCommand { get; private set; }
        public string WindowTitle { get; private set; }
        Window _window;
        private RelayCommand<object> _setRequirements;
        public ObservableCollection<string> List { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<CheckedList> selectedList { get; set; }


        public MigratorAdvancedMigrationOptionsViewModel(Migrator _migrator, CloseClass _Close)
        {
            this.ShowWindowCommand = new RelayCommand<IShowable>(this.ShowWindow);
            this.BackWindowCommand = new RelayCommand<IShowable>(this.Back);
            this._setRequirements = new RelayCommand<object>(Set_Requirements);
            _onClosingCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(OnClosing_Command);
            _Migrator = _migrator;
            this._Close = _Close;

            List = (ObservableCollection<string>)_migrator.GetTables();
            selectedList = new ObservableCollection<CheckedList>();
            CheckedList checkedList= new CheckedList();
            foreach (string item in List)
            {
                checkedList.Text = item;
                SetText = item;
                checkedList.Value = false;
                Checked = false;
                selectedList.Add(checkedList);
            }

        }

        private string _text;
        public string SetText
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SetText");
            }
        }

        private bool _checked;
        public bool Checked
        {
            get { return _checked; }
            set
            {
                _checked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
            }
        }

             [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }
    }
```

it also doesn't work

Comment: What should you be seeing?  Its not clear

Comment: The contetnt of the Combobox. I have only the square from combobox without text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the `ListBox` to `selectedList` which is an `ObservableCollection` of `CheckedList`.  You are binding the Content of the `CheckBox` to CheckedList.SetText when you should be instead be binding to just SetText.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding SetText}" IsChecked="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The data template defines  what to show for each object in the list and the data context will be set to that object i.e. a CheckedList instance.  By putting CheckedList.SetText the binding looks for a CheckedList property in the CheckedList class which doesn't exist.